# Provide c,d such that $ P(c<X<d)=0,95 $ and $P(X<c) =0,025$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the chi-squared distribution $ \chi^2(5) $. Provide c,d such that :

$ P(c<X<d)=0,95 $ and $P(X<c) =0,025$

Any idea on how to calculate this so that both conditions hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(c < X < d) = P(X < d) - P(X \le c)$$

Since chi-squared is continuous, we have $P(X \le c) = P(X < c) = 0.025$

So we have

$P(c < X < d) = P(X < d) - P(X \le c) = P(X < d) - P(X < c) = P(X < d) - 0.025$

Since $P(c < X < d) = 0.95$,

$$P(X < d) = 0.025 + 0.95$$

Now we have:

$$P(X < c) = 0.025$$

$$P(X < d) = 0.975$$

Now use a computer or your chi squared table

to find the c s.t.

$$P(X < c) = 0.025$$

and the d s.t.

$$P(X < d) = 0.975$$

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do would be to find $c$, using your given $P(X<c) = 0.025$. Then figure out what $P(X<d)$ is and use that to find $d$.